# Stored Procedure not working properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure but it's not returning the correct value. I tested taking certain things out and it seems like % is the reason why it's not working properly. Although, `ID` is an `Int` in the database, the program kept failing due to `%` until I changed `IDOld` to `VARCHAR`.

I tested the statement in SQL and it returns the correct value only the stored procedure is returning the wrong value. Also, I tested it by inserting '1' after like and it was still unable to find the value even though it does exists in the database. So not sure how to make this work properly.

I'm getting the old ID and removing the first digit and trying to find the ID that is like the old Id but without the first digit so example IDOld=5623826, IDOld = 623826 than it should return the value that contains IDOld. In the database there are more variations of the ID like 1623826, 2623826,... but I want the last updated value hence using Max.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.UP_getLastUsedIDFromProducts
(
    @IDOld VARCHAR,
    @IDLastUpdated INT OUTPUT,
)
AS
    SELECT @IDLastUpdated = MAX(ID)  
    FROM Products 
    WHERE ID LIKE  '%' + @IDOld

 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UP_getLastUsedIDFromProducts");
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDOld", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbOriginalID.Text;
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDLastUpdated", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Comment: First of all: you **CANNOT** use `LIKE` against an `INT` column! Secondly: if you define a parameter as `VARCHAR` without specifying a **length**; then you get a `VARCHAR` of **exactly one character** in length ....(usually **not** that you want!)

Comment: @marc_s I got it now. I just set the length for the VARCHAR and now it's returning the correct value. TY

Comment: You need to cast the `ID` to a `VARCHAR(9)` in the `WHERE` clause.  Of course its likely to run slowly, and I have serious doubts about the wisdom and utility of this query ...

Comment: @RBarryYoung Yes, that's what I did and now it's working.  TY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a parameter of type `VARCHAR` without giving it a **length** will give you a string of **exactly one character** in length ...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.UP_getLastUsedIDFromProducts
(
    @IDOld VARCHAR,            -- exactly ONE character long
    @IDLastUpdated INT OUTPUT,
)
```

This is most often not what you're looking for - so please **always** specify a length when you define a `VARCHAR` (whether it's used as a parameter, defining a SQL variable, using it in a `CAST` or `CONVERT` statement, or a table definition) !

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.UP_getLastUsedIDFromProducts
(
    @IDOld VARCHAR(20),        -- or whatever fits your needs - just *DEFINE* the length!
    @IDLastUpdated INT OUTPUT,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that comes from not specifying size of `VARCHAR` fields. When you type
`VARCHAR` it is same as `VARCHAR(1)` thus SQL server truncates your input to first character.

Read this https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Additionally you want to avoid implicit conversion between datatypes. This can greatly affect performance of the query in case SQL decides to convert your column instead of parameter. That is why you always want to match data types on both side. You never want `1 = '1'` which will work but will cause problems. That is why it is better to do this `1 = CONVERT(INT,'1')`

Read this - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/turgays/archive/2013/09/16/data-mismatch-on-where-clause-might-cause-serious-performance-problems.aspx